# com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

If the zip code is provided as an input, then corresponding city temperature will be returned as output. Here is my code:

```
public class IPLocationFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String zipCode = args[0];
        Weather service = new Weather();
        WeatherSoap weatherSoap = service.getWeatherSoap();
        WeatherReturn weatherSoap2 = weatherSoap.getCityWeatherByZIP(zipCode);
        System.out.println("The Temperature is" + weatherSoap2.getTemperature());
    }
}
```

I get the following error while executing the above code.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: 
Client received SOAP Fault from server: Server was unable to process request. ---> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.getCityWeatherByZIP(Unknown Source)
at com.kaushik.javabrains.IPLocationFinder.main(IPLocationFinder.java:19)
```

The error happens at the below line. Please suggest.

```
WeatherReturn weatherSoap2 = weatherSoap.getCityWeatherByZIP(zipCode);
```

Comment: `The server was not found or was not accessible.` The Web service seems to be down. Please check the web service details used.

Comment: How to check the web service detail? while creating .java files using wsdl it's working fine.wsdl location:http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL and webservices i used is:https://quicksoftwaretesting.com/sample-wsdl-urls-testing-soapui/ here second one i used.